# How to resolve error after installing plugin?

Tags: plugins

Topic to close. I find errors in my scripts, there was a tons of them like `onchange`  instead of `onChange` and many more syntax.

Comment: A lot more information is going to be required for anyone to help you with this.

Comment: tell me what you need to know...

Comment: Isolate what’s triggering the error and post that portion of your code.  That error could be stemming from literally thousands of things.

Comment: I update post above.

Comment: Off the top, just using my phone, you don’t appear to be closing the comments that establish the plug-in so none of the PHP up to the first ?> tag is executing.

Comment: I do not know. But this not change anything. It show  error named 173 line ``` if ( ! $recursive || ! $this->is_dir( $file ) ) {
   return chmod( $file, $mode ); ```
offtopic, loading this plugin takes a lot of time. I have question if always is necessary a node_modul in plugin if I using react?

Comment: The error message you're getting is in a core WP file if I'm reading the above correctly.  That means that something in your plugin is causing a failure in a WordPress core file.  (Making things a lot harder to troubleshoot).  To answer your question about `node_modules` I never include the directory in my production builds that end up on the actual web server.  I keep them local only.

Comment: I upload this plugin on server. I use npm run build and after that delate node_module. This plugin is active but not working. When I use Gutenberg block I can add "are you playing attention" but it show only a block with message "there is an error so it can be show on screen".